# Aurelia with Typescript: binding using properties doesn't work

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have a custom element in Aurelia using Typescript (2.0), and want to bind some values, but it just doesn't work. Here's my example:

myelement.html:

```
<template>
  <div>${caption}</div>
  <div>${unit}</div>
 </template>
```

myelement.ts:

```
import { bindable } from "aurelia-framework";

export class MyElement {
    // removing the @bindable doesn't change anything
    @bindable public caption: string;
    @bindable public unit: string;
}
```

Usage:

```
<require from="./myelement"></require>
...
<myelement caption.bind="currentvalue" unit=" km"></myelement>
```

The currentvalue property is defined (in the class using the custom element) as

```
public currentvalue: number = 11;
```

The myelement is inserted correctly, but placeholders are replaced with empty text (i.e. removed), even the "unit" which is just a text.

What interestingly does work for the "unit" placeholder is:

myelement.html:

```
<template bindable="unit">
  <div>${caption}</div>
  <div>${unit}</div>
 </template>
```

In this case, the `${unit}` is replaced by " km".

Somehow Aurelia doesn't get the connection between the custom-element's html and viewmodel. Binding using the bindable attribute works, but only if it isn't bound to a property. The myelement.js file gets loaded correctly (I'm using SystemJS with AMD modules).
What have I been missing?

Update:

I changed in myelement.ts `@bindable` to `@bindable()` and now the "unit" is bound correctly - the placeholder in the template is correctly replaced by " km". But the binding using a property (the caption in my case) still doesn't work.

Update 2:
Finally I got it to work. The parent custom element (which uses myelement) was included using `<require from="./myparentelement.html">` so its viewmodel wasn't attached...

Comment: I think your element name should be `<my-element>` instead of `<myelement>` because Aurelia defaults to separating the class name with hyphens for each new capitalized word. Try changing the element in your usage to see if it makes a difference. Or change your class name from `MyElement` to `Myelement`.

Comment: Try writing @bindable() with parenthesis. I read something a while ago about a bug in TypeScript that causes weird behavior when the () are missing. Also you're binding unit to "km" and seem to be expecting the string to make it through to the UI but in this case km will be interpreted as a property. Create a unit property and set its value to 'km', then bind to that

Comment: @LStarky That helped loading the correct file, but not with the binding.

Comment: @mgiesa That helped binding the constant value (yay!), but not with the property binding...

Answer (score 0):

The parent custom element wasn't required properly:
`<require from="./myparentelement.html">` instead of `<require from="./myparentelement">` and I had to use `@bindable()` instead of `@bindable`.